# Get passed Annotation Parameters from Field Annotations

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, field

I have two annotations, this class one:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Processor {
  public String description() default "";
}
```

And also this Field one:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface ProcessorParameter {
    public String name() default "";
    public String value() default "";
    public String[] range() default {};
    public String description() default "";
}
```

They both are getting used in a class like this one:

```
    @Processor(description = "blabla")
    public class Prozessor1{
        @ProcessorParameter(description = "test3")
        public int parameter1;
        @ProcessorParameter(description = "test4")
        public int parameter2;
        @ProcessorParameter(description = "test5")
        public int parameter3;
    }
```

I have different classes of the Prozessor and I want to be able to access all the parameters of the Prozessor and ProcessorParameter Annotation.

Right now I am using this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Reflections ref = new Reflections();
        for (Class<?> cl:
                ref.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Processor.class)){
            Processor processor = cl.getAnnotation(Processor.class);
            System.out.printf("Found class: %s, with meta name: %s%n",
                    cl.getSimpleName(),processor.description());
            for(Field field : cl.getFields()) {
                System.out.printf("Found parameter: %s and %s%n",
                        field.getName(), field.getName());
            }
        }
    }
```

Right now I am getting this as a result:

```
Found class: Prozessor1, with meta name: blabla
Found parameter: parameter1 and parameter1
Found parameter: parameter2 and parameter2
Found parameter: parameter3 and parameter3
```

I obviously do not need the second field.getName() but I want to access the passed ProcessorParameter description ("test3"/"test4"/"test5") but I do not know how to access this.

Comment: You can access the field annotation using `ProcessorParameter param = field.getAnnotation(ProcessorParameter.class);` (this call will return `null` in case the field wasn't actually annotated)

Comment: Yes, you are right. this is the answer to this. Where can I select this as an answer?

Comment: Just made it to the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the `@ProcessorParameter` annotation you just need to invoke this method `getAnnotation(Class<T> annotationClass)` on the `field` object inside the second loop:

```
for(Field field : cl.getFields()) {
    ProcessorParameter param = field.getAnnotation(ProcessorParameter.class);
}
```

**NOTE:** *This call would actually return `null` in case the given annotation is not present on the field*